# Temporary storage for excel file processing

Tags: sql-server, excel, mongodb, jakarta-ee, nosql

I am developing a web application in Java EE technologies(Spring, Spring MVC, Hibernate). In this application I am parsing an Excel file and need to add these data to a sql server database.
Before adding these data to the database I need to get the user input for each row in the Excel file whether they really want to add these data to the database.

I can do this something like this:

- First save the data to a table(table_tmp)
- Then display the data to the user and from their input add it to the actual table and remove from the temporary table.

But I think there will be a better solution (some kind of temporary storage that I can delete after getting user input).

Can I use some NoSQL solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to store it in the first place? You want to allow them to upload that excel, and come back way after their session expired and select rows they want? Do you really have to make it persistent?

If yes, then do you have any problems with your current setup? If not then you'll be introducing another external component that needs to be administered and that you have to interface with (what happens if mongodb is down, not enough disk space, connection timed out, ...) just to keep a temporary file.

But if you still want to do it, then you might first consider something really simple (and fast), like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) - a key-value in-memory storage.